# Finding A Matrix Representation

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

> Let $T=\begin{pmatrix} 
> 3x+3y+3z  \\
> 4x+7y+4z\\
> 6x+8y+6z 
> \end{pmatrix}$ And basis $B=\left\{\begin{pmatrix} 
> 3  \\
> 1\\
> 2
> \end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix} 
> 4  \\
> 2\\
> 3
> \end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix} 
> 2  \\
> 1\\
> 2
> \end{pmatrix}\right\}$  Find $[T]_B$

Now to find it directly I applied T on the elements of $B$ and wrote the coordinates vectors of the images with respect to basis $B$ and got

$$\begin{pmatrix} 
-3 & -5 & -3  \\
10 & 15 & 8\\
-4 & -6 & -3
\end{pmatrix}$$

But how can I get the answer using basis change matrices?

I first need to find $[T]_B^{E}$ the transformation form the standard basis to $B$ which is

$$\begin{pmatrix} 
-5 & -1 & -1  \\
2 & 2 & 1\\
5 & -1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$$

And multiply it by the matrix of basis change $[I]_B^E$ and $[I]_E^B$?
Meaning $[I]_E^B\cdot[T]^E_B\cdot [I]_B^E$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that

$$[T]_E=
\begin{pmatrix} 
3 & 3 & 3  \\
4 & 7 & 4\\
6 & 8& 6
\end{pmatrix}$$

and

$$[M]_{EB}=
\begin{pmatrix} 
3 & 4 & 2  \\
1 & 2 & 1\\
2 & 3& 2
\end{pmatrix}$$

$$v_E=[M]_{EB} \cdot v_B\implies v_B=[M]_{EB}^{-1}\cdot v_E \implies v_B= [M]_{BE}\cdot v_E$$

thus for $w=T(v)$ we have

$$w_E=[T]_{E}\cdot v_E\implies [M]_{EB}\cdot w_B=[T]_{E}\cdot [M]_{EB}\cdot v_B \implies w_B=[M]_{BE}\cdot [T]_{E}\cdot[M]_{EB}\cdot v_B $$

Comment: $[T]_E=[T]_E^E, [M]_{EB}=[I]^E_B ?$

Comment: $[T]_E$ is the matrix associated to T in the standard basis and $[M]_{EB}$ is the matrix whic converts vectors form basis B to standard basis, you can adapt to your conventions

Comment: Shouldn't the last column of $T_E$ be $[3, 4, 6]^{\mathrm t}$?

Comment: @Bernard Yes of course I fix the typo! I've inverted the columns.

Comment: So $$\begin{pmatrix} 
1 & -2 & 3  \\
0 & 2 & -1\\
-1 & -1& 2
\end{pmatrix}*
\begin{pmatrix} 
3 & 3 & 3  \\
4 & 7 & 4\\
6 & 8& 6
\end{pmatrix}*\begin{pmatrix} 
3 & 4 & 2  \\
1 & 2 & 1\\
2 & 3& 2
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} 
-36 & -47 & -31  \\
16 & 26 & 14\\
31 & 47& 26
\end{pmatrix}$$

Which is unlike the correct $[T]_B$